# Problemas con mi contador al tratar de iniciar sesion - php

Tags: php, formularios, session

Tengo problemas con mi contador en el formulario que hice. Solo me cuenta un intento y no los otros que son necesarios  para que se puede bloquear el acceso (2do y 3er intento). Esto es lo único que me falta para terminar mi proyecto .
P.D. ignoren los include

```
<?php
include ("fecha.php");
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['clave'])) {
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $clave=$_POST['clave'];

    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('usuario') or die("cannot select DB");

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='".$email."' AND clave='".$clave."'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername=$row['email'];
    $dbpassword=$row['clave'];
    }

    if($email == $dbusername && $clave == $dbpassword)
    {
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['banned']) && $_SESSION['banned'] > time())
    die('Debes esperar unos minutos antes de ingresar nuevamente al sitio.');

    $_SESSION['sess_user']=$email;
include ("exitoso.php");
    header("Location: Inicio.php");
    }
    } else {
include ("fallido.php");
    echo " <br/> Nombre de usuario invalido o clave incorrecta";
    if(!isset($_SESSION['intentos']))
  $_SESSION['intentos'] = 0;
++$_SESSION['intentos'];
if($_SESSION['intentos'] == 3) {
    $_SESSION['banned'] = time() + 1800;
    die('Superaste el limite de intentos de ingreso... ban!!!');
}
die('.Llevas ' . $_SESSION['intentos'] . ' intentos de ingreso, a la 3ª vez seras baneado por unos minutos.');
    }

} else {
include ("fallido.php");
    echo " <br/> Por favor, ingrese su mail y contraseña";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Hola,tienes que incrementar de esta forma `$_SESSION['intentos']++;`. La consulta sql trae una fila si la contraseña y el usuario son correctos esta demás comparar nuevamente el usuario y la contraseña como lo haces aqui `if($email == $dbusername && $clave == $dbpassword)`

Comment: No te da algun error o notice? Invalid index intentos o algo asi?

Comment: Ya intentaste incrementar de la forma larga ? `$_SESSION['intentos'] = ($_SESSION['intentos'] + 1);`

Comment: ¿Tienes detalle con ese código, porque de quien llevas el error en los intentos? Es decir, si el usuario escribió mal el `email` y no esta registrado, no deberías contarlo como un intento.